# One-to-many relationship not working as expected

Tags: grails

I'm having some problems getting a one to many relationship in grails working properly.
I have a person instance and this person has relationships to other persons. This relationship is defined in a relationship object.
The relevant code is as follows.

```
class Person {
  static hasMany = [relationships:Relationship]
  String name

}

class Relationship {
   Person relationShipTo

   // Enum containing married, living together, parent etc.
   RelationshipType typeOfRelationship
}
```

Now what i want is a one to many reference to that relationship to be persisted but what happens in grails is that it seems to think the relationShipTo instance is refering back to the Person that has this relationship with someone else, and not to the other person.
So a person has a reference to a relationship, and that relationship has a type and a reference to the person with whom you have a relationship with.
I'm not able to change the domain model for this. Is there any way of accomplishing what i want?

What is currently happening if i use the generated views and controllers for the Relationship and try to create a relationship with a type and a person it is refering to, only the type is persisted and the person is ignored. When i then try to add it to the person in the persons edit or create page, all the relationShipTo properties of the relationships i add is saved with the id of the person.

Hopefully what i wrote is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working.

Had to add a static mappedBy =[relationship: 'belongsTo'] to person
and a static belongsTo = [belongsTo: Person].

Not exactly how i wanted it but it works and is an ok compromise

Comment: Can you please add to this answer the code with the changes you made? :)